# too many symbolic links

Tags: linux

I was updating my c++ compiler, and replacing old links with the new ones using the following:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/g++" "g++" "/usr/local/gnu_gcc/4.9.4/bin/g++" 1
```

I accidentally updated cpp with the cpp in the 4.9.4/bin folder,

now I can't update any link because i

> cannot stat file '/usr/bin/cpp': Too many levels of symbolic links

I tried to remove cpp and install it again, didn't sovle the problem,
removing gcc and installing again with remove, or autoremove is not possible because I get the same error again,

any idea how to fix this ?!

Comment: Did you try switching to one of the other alternatives?

Comment: can you elaborate ? I can't update any alternative becuase it keeps giveing me the same error

Comment: You probably have the link pointing to itself. You should easily be able to figure that out using `ls -al`.

Comment: this is what I get from ls -al . : cpp -> /etc/alternatives/cpp

Comment: @drescherjm : this is what I see : cpp -> /etc/alternatives/cpp
I did remove cpp from the system, but the link is still there

Comment: Perhaps  `/etc/alternatives/cpp` points to `/usr/bin/cpp`

Comment: @drescherjm how can I resolve this ? I did try to remove cpp, but it fails with the same error, is there anyway I can force remve it, and reinstall it again

Comment: On gentoo `/usr/bin/cpp` is not a link but a regular file.

Comment: You probably want to `rm /usr/bin/cpp`

Comment: @drescherjm : thanks, it fixed the problem